# Pass variable/parameter to be used another place

Tags: c#

I am new to c# but I need to define the charset used one place of the code (another file) and use this another place. Like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WebClientByteResult, WebClientStringResult>().ForMember(x => x.Content, opt => opt.Ignore()).AfterMap((be, str) =>
        {
            str.Content = Encoding.GetEncoding("CHARSET").GetString(be.Content);
        });
```

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I'm only rewriting some code and have little experience in this language.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple possibilities.

You could use the ChartSet enumeration. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.charset(v=vs.100).aspx)

Or write your own Enum for this purpose

```
public enum CharSet
{
    Charset1,
    Charset2,
    Charset3
}
```

or use a static class with strings.

```
public static class CharSet
{
    public static string Charset1 = "CHARSET1";
    public static string Charset2 = "CHARSET2";
    public static string Charset3 = "CHARSET3";
}
```

There are some possibilities more. But I guess in your case this might be the simples solutions. As a public class you only have to reference the class in your import and you can access them whereever you want to.

Like (Enum)

```
CharSet.Charset1; - // will return the enum -> to get a string use .toString()
```

or (Static class)

```
CharSet.Charset1  - // will return the string
```

I hope this helps

Greez Iki

Comment: Thanks. This was working great, but what if I want du define the charset in multiple places.

I have multiple websites needed to be parsed and everyone have its own .cs file. Then I need to define the charset in each site and use it like shown in the first post.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your setting ? I'm not sure if I unterstood right. As you said; If you need multiple definitions you have to define at multiple places. If its some kind of solution a public class can be used from other dlls. Which means that you could provide the enums through an own project - Maybe you have something like a cross cutting project - this could be the place to put the definition

Answer (score 0):

I still not sure if I really get the point.

But somehow you have to orchestrate your methods calls.

Like

```
ParsePage1.Parse()
ParsePage2.Parse()
ParsePage3.Parse()
```

You could just pass the or the Static class as an method parameter

```
public static class CharSet
{
    public static string Charset1 = "iso-8859-1";
    public static string Charset2 = "iso-8859-1";
} 

public static class Programm()
{
   public static Main(){
       ParsePage1.Parse(CharSet.Charset1);
       ParsePage2.Parse(CharSet.Charset1);
       ParsePage3.Parse(CharSet.Charset2);
    }
}
```

Is this what you mean ? - So you define your charset just ones an reuse it.